# Where can I find the code for the user menu block?

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm trying to code a custom user menu, but I would like to see the original code of the built-in user menu block. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In user.module, all functions with prefix `user_block_` in name.